# Why Isn't my prepared statement working?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

So this works:

```
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['name']);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
$sql= "SELECT password FROM Accounts WHERE username='$name';";
$result= $conn->query($sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

but this doesn't:

```
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['name']);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
//$sql= "SELECT password FROM Accounts WHERE username='$name';";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT password FROM Accounts WHERE username=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$name);
$stmt->execute();
$result= $stmt->get_result();

$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$stmt->close();
```

Why would the first one work, but not the second one? I have PHP 7 installed on my server. I wanna make input secure to avoid SQL injection, but prepared statements aren't working for some reason

EDIT: so using bind_param() and fetch() fixed the problem for me. But I'm still curious why get_result() didn't work. Does get_result() provide just the value selected, whereas my old $result =query() returned the entire row?

My guess is maybe the two methods return different types of data/formats?

Comment: After `$result= $stmt->get_result();`  why this:- `$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`(object+procedure mix). check the example:-http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Comment: The row variable is so that I can do this: if((mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0))
  {
   if (password_verify($password,$row["password"]))

Comment: `$result= $stmt->get_result();while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            print_r($row);
        }`

Comment: define "doesn't work". gives out an error? dies with a white screen? explodes in your face?

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific. I get a 500 error in my browser when I use the script involving prepared statements. code is identical in the two versions besides what I showed in the OP

Comment: @Skilliard  use the code what i have given in comment and remove  `$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`

Comment: Then refer to the link at the top of your question, get the *actual* error message and then google for it

Comment: It's not very descriptive, and Google leads to mixed answers. Like one returns a mysqli_object and the other returns a resultset, but it doesn't explain either of them, and I can't find any sort of comparison of the two on Google.